# Calling predict() inside an R function

Tags: r

I'd like to call predict(...) inside a function in R.  I'm having some trouble related to scoping, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong or how to fix it.  Can anyone help?  Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:20, binary.outcome=1*(runif(20, 0, 1) > 0.60))
summary(df)
logit.model <- glm(df$binary.outcome ~ df$x, family=binomial("logit"), data=df)
summary(logit.model)

PredictOnNewData <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x=51:100)
  df$probability <- round(predict(logit.model, df, type="response"), digits=3)
  return(df)
}

PredictOnNewData()
```

The last line fails with:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`,
>   "probability", value = c(0.274, 0.282,
>   :    replacement has 20 rows, data has
>   50 In addition: Warning message:
>   'newdata' had 50 rows but variable(s)
>   found have 20 rows

If I'm understanding the error message correctly, it looks like the df object I'm passing to predict(...) is being evaluated as the df in the parent / global environment.  That one has 20 rows and was used for training.  But I want the call to predict(...) to be evaluated on the *other* df data frame -- the one I create inside the PredictOnNewData function.  How can I make that happen (without changing the names of my data frames)?

[Now that I re-read this -- am I getting this backwards?  In the line (df$probability <- ...), one of the dfs is being evaluated the wrong way, but which is it?]

I've also tried get("df", envir=sys.frame()), to be explicit about wanting the df object defined in the current function frame:

```
PredictOnNewData <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x=51:100)
  # df$probability <- round(predict(logit.model, df, type="response"), digits=3)
  df$probability <- round(predict(logit.model, get("df", envir=sys.frame()), type="response"), digits=3)
  return(df)
}

PredictOnNewData()
```

...returns the same error as last time.

Please help!

---

It's definitely possible to call predict on a data frame larger than what was used as training data.  An example (runs correctly):

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:20, binary.outcome=1*(runif(20, 0, 1) > 0.60))
summary(df)
logit.model <- glm(df$binary.outcome ~ df$x, family=binomial("logit"), data=df)
summary(logit.model)
df <- data.frame(x=1:100)
df$probability <- round(predict(logit.model, df, type="response"), digits=3)
df
```

That's exactly what I want to do -- except that I want the second df to be created by a function.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the data and formula arguments properly if you want `predict` to work properly. The data argument is a data-frame and the formula argument is composed of column names and (formula) operators. I also don't like the implicit wild extrapolation outside the range of the development domain, but we will ignore that for now. Try this minor modification:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:20, binary.outcome=1*(runif(20, 0, 1) > 0.60))
summary(df)
logit.model <- glm( binary.outcome ~ x, family=binomial("logit"), data=df)
summary(logit.model)

PredictOnNewData <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x=51:100)
  df$probability <- round(predict( logit.model, newdata=df, type="response"), digits=3)
  return(df)
}

PredictOnNewData()
```